# What sets contain $\infty$ and $-\infty$ and why are the Integers closed?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

So I'm currently studying from Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis or colloquially "Baby Rudin" and have stumbled into the second chapter namely basic topology. He lists some sets and states whether or not they are bounded, open, closed or perfect. My question com3es from the fact that he calls the set of all integers closed

By the text a set is closed if every limit point is an element of the set itself. Naturally I understand the only limit points of the Integers to be $\infty$ and $-\infty$... however I assumed that the Integers don't contain either of these elements so I reasoned that the Integers were not closed

Could someone explain why this reasoning is wrong? I presume I'm misunderstanding something...

As a corollary question I was wondering which sets contain $\infty$ and/or $-\infty$

Continuing the story of my study I then assumed that I was wrong and that the Integers do in fact contain $\infty$ and $-\infty$ ( considering the set of complex and real numbers are as well considered closed I assumed that $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are elements of all these sets ) but then Rudin again talks about the set $S = \left\{\frac{1}{n} | \, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ but says that $0$ is not an element (but is obviously a limit point)... I guess the confusion I have comes from the fact that I then assumed that $\infty$ is an element of the natural numbers and earlier he defines $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ so then $0$ should be in the set...

Where is my thinking going awry?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Being "closed" is defined for a subset of another topology/metric space. The integers are closed as a subset of the real numbers. $\pm\infty$ are not in the real numbers. The integers are not closed in the topology of the $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$.

Comment: " Naturally I understand the only limit points of the Integers to be ∞ and −∞"

Why do you think that?  They are not limit points of the integers.  The integers have no limit points at all.  Therefore all limit point (all zero of them) are integers, so the integers are closed.

Comment: I think you are confusing a "limit point" of a set with a "limit" of a sequence.  They aren't entirely different but they are different enough that they might as well be.  Informally, a "limit point" is any point that is infinitely close to a set.  This can include points inside the set as well as points "right up" on the edge.  So a typical set will have lots and lots of limit points.  A "limit" of a sequence, on the other hand is a specific value that all the terms get closer to.  If the sequence converges there is just one limit, and we call it a limit, not a limit point.

Comment: .... although it is a limit point of the set of terms.  (I had never really thought of it that way.)  However it need not be the only limit point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integers are closed in $\Bbb R$, the space of real numbers; $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not in that space and therefore are not relevant. Judging by a quick look at my second edition, he has not at that point talked about $\pm\infty$ or the extended real numbers at all.

Comment: To elaborate slightly, if you apply the strict definition of 'limit point' to the natural numbers, you'll find that $\infty,-\infty$ don't fit it.  You would need for every $\varepsilon>0$ the existence of some integer $n$ such that $|\infty-n|<\varepsilon$. But that's absurd since $\infty-n=\infty$ by its definition.

Comment: then how is it possible to find the limit of a sequence unless $\infty$ is in fact a limit point?

Comment: @Dan: Many sequences of real numbers don’t have limits. For example, the sequence $\langle(-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no limit. The sequence $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no limit in $\Bbb R$; when we write that the limit is $\infty$, we either are using that statement as an abbreviation for the statement that for each $r\in\Bbb R$ there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n>r$ for each $n\ge m$, or are working in the so-called extended reals, which **do** include $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Comment: By applying the definition. $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is well-defined without needing to know what $\infty$ is - think of it as notation, not that $\infty$ is an actual number. (Later, there are ways to formalize it so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ fits into the other definitions of limit, but that's probably too much to get to if you are just starting Rudin.) @DanZimm

Comment: in the third edition he talks about the extended real number in the first chapter - anyways the last comment was referring to the comment above

Comment: As a general rule, in the "extended real numbers" we still should not treat $\pm\infty$ as numbers. Instead, they are points in a topological space. Trying to do arithmetic with them is fraught with risks. @DanZimm

Comment: I understand that infinity is simply a notation not an actual number - question is how can the integers be closed under the reals when infinity is considered a limit point of the integers but isn't in either set - unless infinity isn't a limit point then I understand but this raises the question of how you can take the limit of a function defined on the natural numbers (namely a sequence) when there aren't any limit points

Comment: Suppose $Y$ is a subset of a topological space $X$. We say that a point $x\in X$ is a "limit point of $Y$ **in the space** $X$" if and only if every open subset of $X$ containing $x$ meets $Y\cap(X\setminus\{x\}$. There is no subset of the reals (open or otherwise) containing $\pm\infty$, so $\pm\infty$ are not limit points of the integers (or of any other subset of the reals) **in the space** $\Bbb R$. When we say $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, we mean "the limit as $n$ increases without bound". We aren't actually taking the natural numbers "to $\infty$".

Comment: But I thought the definition of a limit restricts what you take the limit of to a limit point

Comment: @Dan: As I said, we **don’t** consider $\infty$ a limit point of $\Bbb Z$ in the space $\Bbb R$, because $\infty$ isn’t even **in** the space $\Bbb R$. As long as we’re working in $\Bbb R$, the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$, for instance, is **just a handy abbreviation** for a statement about the way the sequence $\langle 0,1,2,\dots\rangle$ behaves. It is **not** a statement that $\infty$ is a limit **point** of the sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: In other words the limit as n approaches infinity, by the definition of a limit, implies that infinity must be a limit point of the domain

Comment: @Dan: I don’t understand your last comment: what you take the limit **of** is a **sequence**.

Comment: @brian then how, by the definition of a limit can we take the limit as n approaches infinity, the definition of a limit species what "n" approaches must be a limit point of the domain

Comment: @Dan: You’re not paying attention: Thomas, Cameron, and I have all said that this is not the case, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$ is merely a notational convenience, a shorthand, when we’re working in $\Bbb R$. One more time: $\infty\notin\Bbb R$.

Comment: What about if the actual limit is a finite number I.e. the sequence of 1/n

Comment: @Dan: Please quote exactly the definition of *limit of a sequence* that Rudin uses in the third edition.

Comment: "Let X and Y be metric spaces; suppose E is a subset of X, f maps E into Y and p is a limit point of E. we write f(x) -> q as x->p if there is a point q in Y with the following property: for every epsilon > 0 there exists a delta > 0 s.t. dY(f(x),q) < epsilon for all points x in E which 0 < dX(x,p) < delta and dX and dY represent the distances in X and Y respectively" sorry for no latex - on tablet

Comment: @Dan: That is the definition of the limit of a *function* on metric spaces, and *not* the definition of the limit of a *sequence of points* in a metric space. In light of the notation $\lim_{x\to p}$, the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is indeed suggestive that $\infty$ is a limit point of the naturals when we consider them as a metric space, but again, this is just a shorthand, meaning we allow $n$ to grow without bound.

Comment: @Dan: As I thought: this is the definition of the limit of a function at a point, **not** the definition of the limit of a sequence. You’re trying to apply its limitations to a different setting to which they do not apply. The definition of limit of a sequence **can** be made to fit that definition, but you’re better off not dealing with that until you’ve acquired a bit more experience with metric spaces generally. In the meantime, realize that it’s a different definition, with slightly different limitations and conventions.

Comment: But I thought a sequence is simply a function with the natural numbers as a domain...

Comment: From rudin: "By a sequence, we mean a function f defined on the set J of all positive integers"

Comment: @Dan: Which are not actually being treated as a subset of $\Bbb R$ in that context. The positive integers are being used there simply as an ordered index set. To make the notion of sequential convergence match the notion of limit of a function at a point, you have to introduce some complexities that I’m pretty sure Rudin omits at this stage.

Comment: So, do we define a special "limit" for functions with certain restricted domains (namely the natural numbers)?

Comment: Gotcha ok - just a bit confusing since you can in fact take the positive integers to be a subset of the R1 metric space

Comment: @Dan: Yes, that’s the best way for you to think about it at this point. If you learn a bit more topology at some point, it will be easy to incorporate the notion of sequential limit into the other notion, but for now you’re better off treating them as two different but closely related concepts.

Comment: Ok - thank you all for your help! Ill accept this answer after this comment. Can't wait to learn topology!

Comment: @Dan: You’re welcome! I think that topology is great fun, but I’m a topologist, so I might be a wee bit prejudiced.

Answer (score 2):

A set $U$ is neither open nor closed implicitly. In the real line $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed, but in the interval $[0,1]$ it is open. Whether a set is considered open is relative to a parent topology.

So we say $U$ is open/closed in another space  $X$. Sometimes, the $X$ is implicit, but when somebody tells you a set $U$ is open, there is always either an explicit or implied $X$.

For example, if $U$ is the set of even numbers, you might think "$U$ isn't open." But it is, when considered as a subset of the integers. The even numbers are not open in the set of real numbers, but that is not a contradiction.

The integers, then, are closed as a subset of the real line. As you rightly note, the integers are not closed as a subset of the extended real line, but I doubt Rudin is asserting that, and there is no contradiction there.

There are some general things you can say. If $U\subset V\subset W$ are topological spaces, then if $U$ is open (closed) in $V$ and $V$ is open (resp. closed) in $W$, then $U$ is open (resp. closed) in $W$.

This doesn't help, though, because if $U$ is the integers, $V$ is the real line, and $W$ is the extended real line, we can't conclude anything from $U$ being closed in $V$ because $V$ is not closed in $W$.

Comment: So does a limit point have to exist in the parent topology to be considered a limit point?

Comment: Yes. When dealing with limit points, we are always talking about in the given topology - there are lots of different ways to "extend" the real line - for example, we can extend the real line with a single $\infty$. There no "natural" extension of the real line that is forced on us. We like the extended real line because it is useful, but inside any topological space $X$, limit points are in $X$.

Comment: Just realized it does ^ stupid question

Comment: It's not a stupid question. Rudin's definitions took me some time to get used to. One of the confusing things in topology is that "closed" and "open" are not opposites. If you know a set is not closed, you don't know it is open, and a set can be both closed and open. You have to get used to that - it can be a bit perplexing at first.

Answer (score 0):

A limit point in a metric space $X$ of a subset $A\subset X$ is a point $x\in X$ for which a sequence $(a_i)_{i\geq 0}$ converges to $x$, with $a_i\in A$ for all $i\geq 0$. The only convergent sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, with the induced topology/metric) are sequences which are eventually constant, further the limit point of such a sequence is simply the integer at which it is constant. It follows that $\mathbb{Z}$ contains all of its limit points and is closed.

Comment: a limit point is not defined by using a sequence, a sequence is defined using a limit point... how can you then claim this?

Comment: I should have been more precise. A limit point of a **subset $A$ of a metric space $X$** is a point $x\in X$ for which there exists a sequence $(a_i)_{i\geq 0}$ such that $a_i\in A$ for all $i\geq 0$ and the sequence $(a_i)_{i\geq 0}$ has $x$ as a limit.

Comment: @Dan: A sequence is simply a function whose domain is $\{k:k\ge n\}$ for some fixed integer $n$, usually $0$ or $1$. It is certainly not true that ‘a sequence is defined using a limit point’. Given a sequence, you can ask whether it converges to some point, and given a point, you can ask whether there is a sequence converging to it, but that’s the only connection.

Comment: The version in your comment still isn’t quite right. If you want $x$ to be a limit point of the **set** $A$, you need to be sure that there is a $1$-$1$ sequence in $A$ converging to $x$; otherwise you get only that $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, possibly for the trivial reason that it’s in $A$.

Comment: The closure of $A$ in $X$ is the set of all limit points of $A$ in $X$ and $A$ is then closed if and only if it is equal to its closure. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: My whole point in my first comment is the limit of a sequence uses the definition of a limit point, not the other way around

Comment: @danielrust that makes more sense but I still seem to be misunderstanding the idea of infinity being a limit point of the integers ( I'm assuming it has to be since you can take the limit of a function defined on the integers )

Comment: Thomas Andrews explains quite nicely in his answer that you need to know both $X$ and $A$ before you can talk about limit points of $A$ as a subspace of $X$. If we are looking at $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $\infty$ isn't a point of $\mathbb{R}$ and so it can't be a limit point. The usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't extend to the set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ very well (you have a problem with defining distance between real numbers and $\infty$).

Comment: So (without using the more sophisticated definition of a convergent sequence of a general topological space) saying a sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ converges to infinity isn't very meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The set of integers contains no limit points and it follows that it is closed, vacuously so. Rudin briefly discusses the extended real numbers in a small section in chapter one towards the end, however he is not using that system in chapter. I would assume if he were it would be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A "limit point" in topology has nothing to do with the limit of a set.  (Which is why I presume you came up with the idea that $\infty$ and -$\infty$ were limit points of the integers?)  A limit pt of a set $A$ is a point $x$ such that every neighbor of $x$ contains a point (other than $x$) of the set $A$.

So, for instance, the point $\frac{1}{2}$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$ because every neighborhood around $\frac{1}{2}$ contains points other than $\frac{1}{2}$ that are in $[0,1)$.  (*Nothing* to do with the limits of $[0,1)$.

So a closed set is one which contains all it's limit pts.  Example:  Every neighborhood of $1$ contains some points in $[0,1)$ so $1$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$.  But $1$ is not a member of $[0,1)$ so $[0,1)$ is not closed.

Consider the integers.  If $x$ is an integer than the neighborhood $(x - \frac{1}{2}, x + \frac{1}{2})$ does not contain any integers other than $x$.  So $x$ is not a limit point of the integers.  Consider $x$ not an integer.  Then you can find a neighborhood around $x$ that has no integers in it.  So $x$ is not a limit point of the integers either.  So the integers have no limit points.  If there are no limit points then it is true that all  of the limit points are in $\mathbb{Z}$ because there aren't any limit points.  So the integers are closed.

So what sets contain $\infty$ and -$\infty$.  Well, as for as Rudin is concerned, only the "extended real number line".  And the *only* purpose for the extended real number line is to have symbols for unbounded quantities.